# Xbox Headset Ear Force X41 - does it really help with gaming?

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

The Ear Force X41 is billed to allow you to hear people sneaking up on you.  They say that the sounds you would miss in your normal speakers you would hear in the head set.  And that since it is surround sound on your ears you will be able to know if they are behind you or not.

I am a bit skeptical of this claim.  And before I [shell out $160](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002KSPKRS) on them, I would like to hear if it really works from someone who owns one of these.  (If there is such a person out there.)

So, if you have used the "Ear Force X41" headset for XBox, please let me know if it really is all they say it is.

Comment: Did you wind up getting them? Was it worth it? I'm thinking about getting the DX11s...I don't mind the wires I think, especially if it means I don't have to provide AAA batteries for the headset.

Answer (score 5):

I use them consistently for Call of Duty, do they help?  Absolutely.  The sound quality is magnificent!  In addition to strong sound quality they also block out a significant amount of background noise which I find vastly helps my concentration (I imagine this is true for most headsets though).

If we are talking about a game like Mass Effect, it probably isn't quite as vital.  Though I noticed a significant spike in my Kill/Death in first person shooters, and a less irritated, tired looking girlfriend after a night of hard-gaming.  In the end it comes down to your priorities and financial liquidity.  Would I buy a pair if it meant I wouldn't eat?  Probably not.  Would I buy another set if I had some spare money?  Definitely.  Take it with a grain of salt as it's really a personal recommendation.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for mentioning it's not worth losing a meal over!